# Can't get buttons to centre using flexbox align-items and justify-content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use flexbox to align a navbar with 4 buttons but I can't get them to align to the center using justify-content and align-items both set to center, feel like I am missing something but can't figure out what.

I have tried wrapping each button in a  but to no avail.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<nav id='nav'>
<span class='button'><button type='button'>Button1</button></span>
<span class='button'><button type='button'>button 2</button></span>
<span class='button'><button type='button'>Button 3</button></span>
<span class='button'><button type='button'>button 4</button></span>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
display: flex;
}

.button {
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put flex options on flex container

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav id='nav'>
    <span class='button'><button type='button'>Button1</button></span>
    <span class='button'><button type='button'>button 2</button></span>
    <span class='button'><button type='button'>Button 3</button></span>
    <span class='button'><button type='button'>button 4</button></span>
  </nav>
</body>
```